# vim: set nocursorbind after Gdiff with fugitive plugin

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

when I use Gdiff, this open a window with differences, but when I close the window differences the cursorbind is 1.

How I can set nocursorbind when I close the window differences ?

I think in

```
autocmd BufDelete fugitive* set nocursorbind
```

but don't work

Answer (score 0):

for now I set this map

```
nn <silent><Leader>gD <c-w>h:bd<cr>:setl nocursorbind<cr>
```